# VBA combobox with autocomplete and search as you type

Tags: excel, vba, filter, combobox, autocomplete

I have the below code which creates a userform with autocomplete which I copied from another website. I would like to modify this to include a "search as you type" feature. for example:

the table the combo box references is 1 column and includes items like this:

```
chevy truck
ford truck
truck
chevy car
ford car
car
```

Currently when the user types "truck" the only result and suggestion is "truck" and will not show 'chevy truck'

I would want the drop down list to show something like this when the user searches 'truck'

```
truck
chevy truck
ford truck
```

or if the user types "tr" the list will show:

```
truck
chevy truck
ford truck
```

user types 'che'...list shows:

```
chevy truck
chevy car
```

etc.

```
Private Sub OEM_Change()
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String
'x = this is where i need help.
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
str = Me.OEM.Value
    If str <> "" Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            If InStr(LCase(x(i, 1)), LCase(str)) > 0 Then
                dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
    Me.OEM.List = dict.keys
    Else
    Me.OEM.List = x
    End If
    Me.OEM.DropDown

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Vertical
     .AddItem "vertical1"
     .AddItem "vertical2"
     .AddItem "vertical3"
     .AddItem "vertical4"
     .AddItem "vertical5"
End With

End Sub

Private Sub Vertical_Change()

Dim index As Integer
 index = Vertical.ListIndex

Select Case index
     Case Is = 0
         With OEM
             .RowSource = "Namedrange1"
         End With
     Case Is = 1
         With OEM
             .RowSource = "Namedrange2"
         End With
     Case Is = 2
         With OEM
            .RowSource = "Namedrange3"
         End With
    Case Is = 3
         With OEM
            .RowSource = "Namedrange4"
         End With
    Case Is = 4
         With OEM
            .RowSource = "Namedrange5"
         End With

End Select

End Sub
```

for reference: some of this code came from this thread

[searchable combo box with a list of sugggestion on a userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076069/searchable-combo-box-with-a-list-of-sugggestion-on-a-userform?)

Comment: I may also add to this that the referenced table for this combobox is ever growing and currently has over 300 entries. so it would be too complicated to somehow look for each item specifically in the code with if/then or case statements

Comment: A UserForm is the way to go. You say you can't use one because you'd have to change the design of your workbook. But how about a small userform which is shown only on a SelectionChange event where the target is the specific cell in question? You could even make that userform detect keypresses other than typing: eg if the user presses a cursor key, the form should close and then select another relevant worksheet cell (same behaviour as keying through cells).

Comment: @ChrisMelville i'll look into this. thanks

Comment: @chrismelville I edited my code went with your userform idea. however I've hit a roadblock. getting various errors when this runs.. I can't figure out what I need to set the variable x to. the code I pulled from the web says set to a range on a worksheet but the combobox this is working out of is dependent on another combobox and the rowsource is prefilled before the oem_change event occurs. keep getting error 70 or object reference errors. the dropdown will fill the list with the correct items, but as soon as I start typing in the 2nd combobox (oem) it errors out.

Comment: so x is supposed to be an array for the ubound property to work, so I guess how do you take whats already in the combobox list and define it as an array, setting the variable "x" to it? or maybe im not on the right track at all im not sure

Answer (score 1):

ok guys I figured it out. I dim'ed another variable as "p". p = vertical.value, then x = worksheets("sheet2").range(p).value. works perfect. thanks to all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete when typing in drop down list with VBA code

Firstly you need to insert a combo box into the worksheet and change its properties, and then running the VBA code to enable the autocomplete.

1. Get into the worksheet which contains the drop down list you want it to be autocompleted.
2. Before inserting the Combo box, you need to enable the Developer tab in the ribbon.

1). In Excel 2010 and 2013, click File > Options. And in the Options dialog box, click Customize Ribbon in the right pane, check the Developer box, then click the OK button. See screenshot:

2). In Outlook 2007, click Office button > Excel Options. In the Excel Options dialog box, click Popular in the right bar, then check the Show Developer tabin the Ribbon box, and finally click the OK button.

3. Then click Developer > Insert > Combo Box under ActiveX Controls. See screenshot:
4. Draw the combo box in current opened worksheet and right click it. Select Properties in the right-clicking menu.
5. In the Properties dialog box, you need to:

1). Change the name to TempCombo in the Name field;

2). Specify the font you need in the Font field;

3). Scroll down to select 1-fmMatchEntryComplete in the MatchEntry field;

4). Close the Properties dialog box.

6. Turn off the Design Mode with clicking Developer > Design Mode.
7. Right click on the current opened worksheet tab and click View Code. See screenshot:
8. Make sure that the current worksheet code editor is opened, and then copy and paste the below VBA code into it.

CAN'T SEEM TO PASTE CODE IN HERE FOR SOME ODD REASON...

9. Click File > Close and Return to Microsoft Excel to close the Microsoft Visual Basic for Application window.
10. Now, just click the cell with drop down list, you can see the drop-down list is displayed as a combo box, then type the first letter into the box, the corresponding word will be completed automatically. See screenshot:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2401-excel-drop-down-list-autocomplete.html#a1

Comment: I believe you have posted almost the exact same code I did. you may have found the website I pulled mine from. doesn't really help me though and this code only filters the list to an exact match of what you typed. I need a modified version that can search a string and return any part of that string

Comment: I edited my original answer.  Now, I can't seem to post the VBA code into the window...very weird...  Anyway, check the link and you 'll get all code from there.  People at this site don't take favorably to just posting a link, so I listed all steps along with the link.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

For anyone trying this with a ComboBox on a VBA form John_w's answer from the below link is a better solution:

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-use-a-combobox-with-autocomplete-and-search-as-you-type.1098277/

EDIT - Info from the page in case it is ever removed as per SO bot suggestion:

Try this code. The combo box is an ActiveX Combo Box with the following properties:

```
Name = ComboBox1
ListFillRange = blank
MatchEntry = 2 - fmMatchEntryNone
MatchRequired = False
```

The combo box values are in Sheet1 starting at A2 to the last populated cell in column A.

Put this code in the module of the sheet containing the combo box.

```
Option Explicit

Private IsArrow As Boolean

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim i As Long
    
    If Not IsArrow Then
        With Me.ComboBox1
            .List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
            .ListRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(6, .ListCount)
            .DropDown
            If Len(.Text) Then
                For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
                    If InStr(1, .List(i), .Text, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then .RemoveItem i
                Next
                .DropDown
            End If
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    IsArrow = (KeyCode = vbKeyUp) Or (KeyCode = vbKeyDown)
    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then Me.ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)