# Creating type search sensitive combobox in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am new to VBA. Generally, I will use the Excel functions to get along with my own internal analysis, etc.  However, at a new start-up company with resources thin on the ground, I need to create a user from where users can search through a list of occupations and when found, it should display a list of parameters attached to that occupation in text boxes without being able to change those values other than entering a new occupation to search.

I started off with my spreadsheet (4610 rows of data with 11 columns of data next to each). What I try to create is an alpha sensitive type search combo box where the user should start typing an occupation they are searching for and it should list say 8 occupations as the user type and he can then select the correct one which should then display the other parameters on the user form.

I have started with the user form, selected the ComboBox from the tools and the other text boxes where the data should be displayed.

I went into the Properties of the ComboBox and set the MatchEntry to 1 - fmMatchEntryComplete and ControlTipText **Start typing the occupation you are looking for** and the ListRows to 8.

I searched on StackOverflow for guidance and adapted the code displayed in [the following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076069/searchable-combo-box-with-a-list-of-sugggestion-on-a-userform)?

Here is my code for the ComboBox:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x, dict
Dim i As Long
Dim str As String

Set ws = Sheets("Occupations")
Set Rng = ws.Range(Cell1:="C2")


x = ws.Range("C2").Value
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
str = Me.ComboBox1.Value
If str <> "" Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        If InStr(LCase(x(i, 1)), LCase(str)) > 0 Then
            dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = ""
            End If
        Next i
        Me.ComboBox1.List = dict.Keys
Else
    Me.ComboBox1.List = x
End If
Me.ComboBox1.DropDown


End Sub
```

My occupation list (4610 entries) is in column C2 in worksheet Occupations.

The code for UserForm_Initialise is as follows:

```
Dim occupationName As Range

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Occupations")


  For Each occupationName In ws.Range(Cell1:="C2")
   With Me.ComboBox1
    .AddItem occupationName.Value
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = occupationName.Offset(0, 1).Value
   End With
 Next occupationName

Me.ComboBox1.SetFocus
Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Type text to open a list of choices"

End Sub
```

When I run the code, I get a

> Run-time error '94' Invalid use of Null

in `str = Me.ComboBox1.Value`

I have tried a couple of other threads and also tried to use the Nz notation but Excel VBA does not recognize it.

Any help will be appreciated.  I can fiddle further and still learn through other means but is unfortunately, running out of time for this solution.

Comment: Try changing it to `str = Me.ComboBox1.Value & ""`

Answer (score 0):

I think you has not init the scripting dictionary correctly. the NEW statement is missing.
So the scripting dictionary has never done its own hidden setup and will fail.

somewhere in the module head maybee

```
  dim dict as scripting.dictionary
  set dict = NEW scripting.dictionary 'has to be a new ones ;)


  sub dictionary_reset(dict as scripting.dictionary) 'reset the created dictionary
    on error resume next
    err.clear
    on error resume next
     dict.clearAll
     if err.number <>0 then  debug.print err.description 
  end sub
```

here you  can run over your range and overwrite existing entrys or add new ones.
if you want to start from beginning use the dictionary_reset sub first

```
  function addentry(dict as scripting.dictionary key as string ,entry as string ) as 
   boolean 'this you will need very often...
    addentry=false
    on error resume next
    err.clear
     if not dict.exist(key) then
        dict.item(key)=entry;
     else
        dict.add key , entry 
     end if
        if err.number <>0 then  debug.print err.description 
     addentry=err.number=0
  end function
```

this here will becomes true if a key is found. The result will be in entry. So you know what you can await before taking other actions. Sometimes handy.

```
  function searchentry(dict as scripting.dictionary key as string ,entry as string ) as 
        boolean
     searchentry=false
     err.clear 
     on error resume netx
     if dict.exists(key) then 
      searchentry=true
      entry=dict.item(key)
     endif
    if err.number <>0 then  debug.print err.description
  searchentry =err.number=0
  end function
```

it is understandable that you want to use as much as possible from known excel.
with some practice you will go the opposite way. Think about "IF" in excel ;)
Might be a idea to go immidiatly the opposite way. It makes also the code reusable in other applications. It is also a great idea to outsource such functions. Then you can debug them easy either by a test routine without the gui stuff. And most important they can be reused.
I usually add also some error handling things.

BTW: VBA is also nothing else then VB6. If you do not find code in VBA you might find code for VB6.

Have fun here and enjoy VBA :)